# laravel 5.1 database queue not working

Tags: php, email, queue, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to use database driver for queuing emails. Using `Mail::send` emails are sent as expected. But when I use `Mail::queue` the user object passed to the view gets `null` "Trying to get property of non-object".

I have a mailer class and these are the methods responsible for sending the email:

```
 public function sendAssignmentEmail(User $user)
    {
        $this->to=$user->email;
        $this->view='emails.assigned';
        $this->data=compact('user');
        $this->subject='subject';
        $this->deliver();
    }

public function deliver()
    {
        $to=$this->to;
        $subject=$this->subject;
        $from=$this->from;
        return $this->mailer->queue($this->view,$this->data, function($message)
        use($to, $subject, $from)
        {
            $message->from($from, 'example.com');
            $message->to($to);
            $message->subject($subject);
        });
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?
I know that the problem is with the

```
$this->data
```

If I pass an array the queue will work, but if the data is in form of an object it won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mail::queue` is essentially exactly the same as `Mail::send` except your queuing them to be sent.

As a result it expects the same parameters as `Mail::send` in which the second argument needs to be an array, hence why it works when you supply an array and doesn't when you supply an object.

Simply change `$this->data=compact('user');` to be in the form of an array and it'll work fine for you.

The [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail#sending-mail) are super useful when you get stuck on things like this :).

Comment: I didn't get what you mean!

Comment: Finally I got what you mean.  Thank you a lot. I passed an array in stead of an object as data